# "Hello. Could I speak to Sue, please?" or "Hello. Could I talk to Sue, please?"? Which one is correct?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

[This page](http://thefreedictionary.com/talk) says:

> When you make a telephone call, you ask if you can speak to someone.
>   You don't ask if you can '**talk to**' them.
>
> *Hello. Could I speak to Sue, please?*

But in fact, a lot of native people says

*Hello. Could I talk to Sue, please?*

See [this English teaching video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9cZ0FqRIWlY) at **4:22**

"**Can I talk to Phil Watson, please?**"

So, **who is right?**

"**Hello. Could I speak to Sue, please?**" or **"Hello. Could I talk to Sue, please?**"? *Which one is correct?*

Comment: Both are correct. **speak to** is somewhat more formal.

Comment: Sounds like BrE to me. Maybe the common usage is different for AmE or others.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. However, you might try, "Hello. **May** I speak **with** Sue, please?" Better is, "Hello, this is Tom Smith. Is Sue available to speak with?" (This is a matter of etiquette, not grammar.)

Answer (score 1):

The fact you said "Hello." and "please" indicates a formal context.

To stay consistent, so you should use *may* and *speak*. *talk* is kind of like *chat* and more informal. So:

> Hello. **May** I **speak with** Sue, please?

(AmE disclaimer)